# Postgres - Revoke access to public schema for a user

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

As a DBA, I have created a user `user1` to access `abcd` schema as per the request.

But, the user I have created is also getting read access to the schema `public` in the database. An application owner requested me to `REVOKE` the access to `public` schema from the user `user1` that I have created. For that, I am using the following `REVOKE` statements, which are not revoking the access to `public` schema for the user `user1`.

```
REVOKE ALL ON schema public FROM user1;
```

...and then tried:

```
REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
```

I am still able to read a table in the `public` schema from `user1` user.

Am I missing something here?

I have also taken the pg_dump of the database with `schema-only` to see if there any other grants that are assigned to the user `user1` but found none.

Comment: Try: REVOKE SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM user1;

Comment: Did you close and re-open the connection for user1 after the changes before testing?

Answer (score 4):

The `public` schema is unique in that anyone that connects to the database inherits a `public` role. Unlike other user-defined roles, the *public* role cannot be dropped -- it's a "reserved" role -- but its permissions can be modified.

### Removing Permissions

The solution might be a little more cumbersome than you'd think. First, you were close with revoking the users permissions. That is an ability, but you never explicitly granted the user permission, they only inherited by default.  So remove the permissions from the default:

```
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM public;
```

At this point the only users that can see the *public* schema and its objects are database *owners* and *superusers*. Remember, permissions are additive (not restrictive).

### Granting Permissions

Since you removed the ability for everyone to access, if you'd like others to be able to access *public* you'll have to be explicit and grant them access.

| Command | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO <user>;` | Allows to see and select from tables in *public* |
| `GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO <user>;` | Allows to create in *public* schema; however, they must also have usage permission |

This task can be tedious and although it may not save you any text, it might easier to have a way to quickly restrict everyone from public at some point in the future -- let's say there's a security breach or heavy misuse or a big mistake and you need time to address. For that, you create a new role.

### Roles

Roles can be instrumental in granting access and permissions. Since permissions are additive, it's good to think about your role strategy.  One potential solution is to create a general role (or a public role that you can control).

```
CREATE ROLE rw_public;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO rw_public;
```

For your new users you can usually grant them access through your automation script. Manually the process would look like:

```
-- grant permission
GRANT rw_public TO <user>;

-- remove permission
REVOKE rw_public FROM user;


-- NOTE: users need to reconnect for the roles to go into effect
```

So, if something happens permissions can be quickly revoked from the role and the database can be restarted with minimum downtime.  Of course, there are other ways to kick users out without shutting down the server and you can target accounts that inherit from that role.